# List of log tables to safely truncate in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, database, sql, optimization

For Magento 1, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28057465/1728526) is a list of log/cache tables which can be safely truncated.

Is there a similar list of tables for Magento 2, which can be truncated/deleted without deleting base data?

Please note that I do not want to delete any real data like customer, product, sales, quote etc. I want to clear only log related tables to free space and optimize the database.

Comment: Check this out, all required tables are mentioned in the script - https://gist.github.com/leek/f7fd2c41668b0f8a0a5f6e5209fe8f4e

Answer (score 0):

Truncating the table from the database may be dangerous So, If you want to truncate then take a backup first then do it. Here I write some of the tables that you truncate but truncate according to their description

**Here are some of the tables that you can truncate**

**catalog_product_entity** - This table contains product information you can truncate if you don't have the custom attribute.

**catalog_product_entity_datetime, catalog_product_entity_decimal, catalog_product_entity_int, catalog_product_entity_text, catalog_product_entity_varchar** -

These tables are EAV Tables that product attributes value. if you don't have any custom attribute then you can truncate it.

**catalog_product_entity_tier_price** -If you don't use tier price then you can truncate this table

**catalog_product_index_eav, catalog_product_index_eav_decimal, catalog_product_index_eav_decimal_idx, catalog_product_index_eav_decimal_tmp, catalog_product_index_eav_tmp, catalog_product_index_eav_index** -

These tables are the index tables to speed up you can truncate but then the index will rebuilt

**report_event, report_compared_product_index, report_viewed_product_index** - These tables are used for the reporting purpose. you can truncate if you don't have enough reporting data.

Comment: Hi Grazitti, I want to delete only log related tables. Not any actual data.